# Relationship between the number of distinct roots of $f$ and the degree of the gcd of $f$ and $f'$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

> $n_0(f)=\text{deg} f - \text{deg}(f, f^\prime)$, where $n_0(f)$ is the number of *distinct* roots of $f(x)$, $\text{deg} f$ is the degree of $f(x)$ and $\text{deg}(f, f^\prime)$ is the degree of the GCD of $f$ and the first derivative of $f$

I saw this theorem in a book with no proof and no citation. I know I should be providing what I have tried but I really do not know where to start. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Could you please at least provide some context about (i) which book you're reading and (ii) how much progress you've made through the book?

Comment: I speak Chinese at the level of a two-year-old, which is not terribly helpful here. Besides, I don't own this book. What we're really asking for is context about any knowledge you may have that is relevant for this problem. This is to ensure that answers will be written at an appropriate level.

Comment: um I have learnt basic derivatives but not abstract algebra or matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume characteristic $0$ or at least that $f$ does not have a root with multiplicity divisible by the characteristic, otherwise the statement fails, eg with $f(x) = x^p$ over a field of characteristic $p$.

Pass to the algebraic closure so that the statement holds verbatim. If $r$ is a root of $f$ with multiplicity $m > 0$ then it is a root of $f'$ with multiplicity $m - 1$. One way to see this is to write $f(x) = (x-r)^m g(x)$ with $g(r) \ne 0$ so that $f'(x) = (x-r)^{m-1}(m g(x) + (x-r)g'(x))$. Now, using/assuming unique factorization of polynomials, if $f(x) = \prod_i (x - r_i)^{m_i}$ with $r_i$ distinct then $\gcd(f, f')(x) = \prod_i (x - r_i)^{m_i - 1}$, from which the required statement follows immediately.

If the polynomials are over a field that is not algebraically closed but is of characteristic $0$, then the correct statement is that $\deg f - \deg \gcd(f, f')$ is the number of roots of $f$ in the algebraically closure, with the same proof.